# How to determine if strings are equal in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, c-strings

I read a string from a JSON result as follows:

```
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] 
                                               length:[data length] 
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I then try to determine if the string is equal to the value "N"

```
if ([strResult isEqualToString:@"N"])
{ 
  [lblImageOK setHidden:YES]; 
} 
else 
{ 
  [lblImageOk setHidden:NO]; 
}
```

The if statement allways returns the else part, even though the result is "N". They both have the same value but the statement returns false always.

Comment: Can you `NSLog(@"%@",strResult);` before your if statement and add the output to your question?

Comment: Make it `NSLog(@"[%@] len=%d, strResult, [strResult length]);` for good measure.

Comment: as peterept suggests, you almost certainly have leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: This is what I get with the NSLog:  ["N"] len=3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a way to clean the string and then check if they are equal.

```
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] 
                                           length:[data length] 
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

strResult = [strResult stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
strResult = [strResult stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

if ([strResult isEqualToString:@"N"])
{ 
  [lblImageOK setHidden:YES]; 
} 
else 
{ 
  [lblImageOk setHidden:NO]; 
}
```